# Exporting types from private headers via the public header

Tags: c

From what I understand, protection of implementation is a good principle to follow, so when writing a new library I decided to give it a shot. My goal is to protect internally used data types and only export the ones that are absolutely needed for people implementing my library.

Let say I have four files:

library_component.c:

```
#include "library_component.h"

struct my_data {
    int stuff;
};
```

library_component.h:

```
// Private header
struct my_data;
```

library.c

```
#include "library_component.h"
#include "library.h"
```

library.h:

```
// Public header
// Include guards, etc...

typedef struct my_data my_data_type;
```

In this example `library_component.c` and `library.c` would get compiled into a shared library file `library.so` and installed along with `library.h` inside the host machine.

What's unclear to me, is how am I supposed to handle the `struct my_data` situation. I want to export it is as `my_data_type`. Is it possible to hide the typedef statement from the public header?

Comment: dividing into C/H files is very old concept, i guess has not too much with encapsulation. Maybe think about migration to C++ with stage "C with classes" ?

Comment: *"Is it possible to hide the typedef statement from the public header?"* Why would it be necessary? Internals of `struct my_data` are already hidden. User can use `struct my_data`, when you would want him to use `my_data_type`, but that is really all he can do.

Comment: @JacekCz Except this happens to have everything to do with encapsulation. Only providing an incomplete type in the header is a common method to get private encapsulation in C.

Comment: @user694733 You're right. I guess this still applies because of _aesthetic purposes_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `library` is the only module exposed to the caller - it is the actual API - then this design is fine. A nosy caller, who for some reason goes to dig up internal header files only used by `library`, can't do much with it anyway - `struct my_data` in the header is an incomplete type.

However, a less confusing alternative might be to write `library_component.h` as:

```
typedef struct my_data_t my_data_t;
```

And then use that very same definition in `library.h` - the type is declared in `library_component.h` and `library.h` gets access through it with `#include`. Then everything will be clear. In `library_component.c` you would have `struct my_data_t { ...`.

And finally, all functions in `library.h` should be designed to use `my_data_t*`, which is a must since the type is incomplete and the caller won't be able to create instances of it.

This design method is known as *opaque type*/*opaque pointers*.

Comment: For clarification in phrasing, functions in `library.h` should be designed to use `my_data_t *` when they need to refer to a `my_data_t` object. They should not be designed to use `my_data_t *` if they only need a `double` or a `struct SomethingElse`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide the `typedef` from the users of the library because that is the type you want your users to use.  This is not a problem in terms of protecting private types however.

The `typedef` acts as a forward declaration of `struct my_data`.  So users of the library can create pointers to that type but not instances of that type.  That protects the implementation details of `struct my_data`.

For example, your library can include functions like this:

```
struct my_data *get_new();
void do_something(struct my_data *data);
void do_something_else(struct my_data *data);
void cleanup(struct my_data *data);
```

These allow users to create instances of the struct via `get_new`, receiving a pointer to the instance, and to pass that pointer to other library functions to operate on it.